# check condition only if a condition is met within an if then

Tags: delphi

I have an example of a code and not sure what way is the best to use.

For example I have

```
if (x = 1) and (y = 2) and (if abc = false then check if z = 3) then
begin
  ...
```

check only

```
if x = 1
if y = 2
if abc = false check z = 3. if abc = true then dont check z = 3
```

i am not sure if i am explaining the best but hopefuly people will understand.

I want to know if this is possible or the best way to do it. Keeping in mind that rather than in example where its x, y, z and abc. there can be more in my use.

I currently have structure as...which i dont think is practical, and think theres a better way but i am not sure

```
if (abc = false) then
begin
  if (x = 1) and (y = 2) and (z = 3) then
  begin
    ...  
end
else
begin
  if (x = 1) and (y = 2) then
  begin
    ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that you don't have to test for whether an expression is equal to `True` or `False`.  You can simply write `if abc` or `if not abc`, if abc is a boolean variable or expression.

Comment: FWIW, for such cases, you should make a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). That will help you to see how to code it.

Comment: Yea, I am aware i can write "if abc" or "if not abc", but wrote this way to clarify my intent. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `or`. Now you will check that x must be 1, y must be 2, and if abc is false, z must be 3.

If abc = true, z can still be three, but it won't be checked.

Note that I just wrote `abc` instead of `abc = true`. Since it's a Boolean (true/false) already, that's allowed.

Also note how the operations are grouped using parentheses. The total sub-expression `abc or (z=3)` must return true for the total expression to return true.

Furthermore the *sequence* of the terms is significant - they are evaluated left-to-right. If the term `(abc or (z=3))` is replaced by the logically-equivalent term `((z=3) or abc)` then `z=3` **will** be evaluated.

```
if (x = 1) and (y = 2) and (abc or (z = 3)) then
   // Your magic goes here
```

Test program body to prove sequence is important

```
function z : Integer;
begin
  writeln('Z being evaluated');
  result := x + y;
end;

begin
  x := 1;y := 2;
  abc := true;
  if (x=1) and (y=2) and (abc or (z=3)) then
    writeln ('evaluated true')
  else
    writeln ('evaluated false');
  writeln('done');
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Seems I skimmed the question too quickly. My response was quite erroneous, hence deleted. Hope my edit above clarifies what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your code samples compile, because neither is using the proper syntax.

This should get you started:

```
if (x = 1) and (y = 2) then
begin
  if (abc) then 
    // Handle abc = True
  else 
  begin
    if (z = 3) then
      // Handle abc = false and z = 3
    else
      // Handle abc = false and z <> 3
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The expression "Faster than a speeding bullet" springs to mind!

Comment: @MartynA: Happened to just refresh the page when it appeared. :-) Pure luck.

Comment: Not sure that is what he wants. I thought he meant: `if not abc then if z = 3 then { z = 3 part } else { z <> 3 part} else { abc true part };`

Comment: @Rudy: Read the first line of the first code snippet (which seems to explain the logic desired, even if the syntax is not even close to being correct). Also read the poster's newly added third code snippet.

Comment: @Ken: to me, it looks as if your recents mods are just a rearrangement of what I wrote. <g>